# Как получить названия столбцов в php из запроса sql

Tags: php, sql

Задача, как для каждого столбца выполнить проверку. пробежаться по всем так сказать в цикле(обращаясь по имени столбца (например $row[$nazvanie_stolbca]=1), а не перечислять, т.к. долго.

З.Ы. "Сформировать потом строку запроса и обновить пачкой в БД"

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wt_pto_db` where list_id =  " . $_GET[id];
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                print_r($row);
                                echo "<hr>";
                                foreach ($row as $val)
                                {
                                    echo $val."=";
                                }
                            }
                        }
$conn->close();
```

*Тут есть названия столбцов   (print_r($row))*

```
Array ( [db_id] => 1 [list_id] => 2 [id_num] => 321 [num_svai_po_proektu] => [Dubl_za_schet] => [Privjazka_BS_OSI] => [num_svai_po_ZhPS] => [Data_pogruzhenija_svai] => [num_zajavki] => [Tip_svai] => [Tip_niz] => [Tip_verh] => [Beton_RD] => [Armatura_RD] => [Dlina_svai_pm] => [RD_usilie_min] => 0 [RD_usilie_max] => 0 [Usilie_vdavlivanija_fakt] => 0 [Kontrol_usilija_vdavlivanija] => [Fakt_pogruzhenija] => [Otmetka_grunta] => [Ab_Otm_golovy] => [H_RCh] => [Otmetka_ostrija_svai_RD] => [Otmetka_ostrija_svai_GS] => [Dodavlivanie] => [NDP_EO] => [Otkl_H] => [Sverka_NDP] => [num_ANDPS] => [Glubina_pogruzhenija_svai_ot_proektnoj_otmetki_golovy] => [Glubina_pogruzhenija_svai_ot_otmetki_grunta] => [Dlina_sruba_fakt] => [Foto_sruba] => [AGSP] => [num_ID] => [num_KS] => [Prokol] => [numpp_skvazhiny_po_ZhBS] => [Data_burenija] => [Diametr_burenija_mm] => [Diametr_burenija_po_RD_dlja_Zakazchika_mm] => [Otmetka_zaboja_skvazhiny_RD] => [Glubina_burenija_fakt_m] => [Glubina_burenija_m_dlja_Zakazchika] => [Pombur] => [KA_Pombur] => [OtklX] => [OtklY] => [Otklonenie_po_LKP_vdol_cifr_osej_mm] => [Otklonenie_po_LKP_vdol_bukv_osej_mm] => [Kontrol_vedetsja] => [Vertikal_po_foto_vdol_cifr_osej] => [Vertikal_po_foto_vdol_bukv_osej] => [Fakt_NDO] => [Naimenovanie_SVU] => [FIO_brigadira_SVU] => [FIO_proraba_mastera] => [Probnoe_pogruzhenie_fakt] => [IGI_fakt_SI] => [Data_nachala_SI] => 0000-00-00 [Data_okonchanija_SI] => 0000-00-00 [num_pasporta_celnaja_svaja] => [Data_pasporta_celnaja_svaja] => [Zavodskoj_nomer_celnaja_svaja] => [num_pasporta_NIZ] => [Data_pasporta_NIZ] => [Zavodskoj_nomer_NIZ] => [num_pasporta_VVERH] => [Data_pasporta_VVERH] => [Zavodskoj_nomer_VVERH] => [pp_passport] => [Primechanija] => )
```

Тут нет *echo $val."=";*

```
1=2=321=============0=0=0===========================================0000-00-00=0000-00-00============
```

Comment: не обязательно писать имя. можно по индексу обращаться. $row[0], $row[1] и т.д.

Comment: а в чем суть проверки?

Comment: Суть в том есть ли значение в ячейке или нет. если нет внести, а если есть то не вносить. Допустим если применить не к sql запросу, а к POST массиву. например, как получить все названия столбцов из POST массива. Смысл в данном случае тот же

Comment: php.net/foreach но запрос ты составляешь неправильно

Comment: Подскажите что не корректно в данном запросе?

Comment: всё. запросы так не составляют. тем более из массива пост

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $field)
{
    echo $_POST[$field];
}
```

Нашёл решение $field содержит поля формы html.